# CSS- Family-font for single line and multiline text control

Tags: css, fonts, textarea, multiline

I have 2 Textbox controls in my page. SingleLine and MultiLine.

I notice the default Family-fonts between multilines and singleline Textboxes are different. I've checked it comes from the same CSS sheet and same line as well.

Not sure why its different and how to fix it. Google doesn't help much.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this in your css

```
input[type='text'],
textarea{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

or if you have any class with your textbox and textarea do like this

```
input[type='text'].your_class,
textarea.your_class{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Munshi Azhar! How do we go with the ID? Is this right?

`input[type='text']#inner_editor, textarea#inner_editor
{
font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
}`

Comment: This works only when the `input` elements have an explicit (not defaulted) `type=text` attribute. If they dont’t, you may need more complicated CSS code, depending on the presence of other `input` elements and their desired rendering.